# How to remove "No File Chosen" from django image form

Tags: python, django

I have a Django profile edit form. When i render the html page, it gives me the choose file button. But it also has `No File Chosen` along with it. I want to remove this, and only keep the `choose file` button part.

below if my `views.py`

`views.py`

```py
@login_required
def edit_profile_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserEditForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect("edit_profile_view")
    else:
        u_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        "u_form": u_form,
        "p_form": p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/edit_profile.html', context)
```

here is my `forms.py`

`forms.py`

```py
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label=('Image'),required=False, error_messages = {'invalid':("Image files only")}, widget=forms.FileInput)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image', 'organization', 'name', 'bio']

        widgets = {
            "organization": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            "name": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            "bio": forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'rows': 3})
        }
```

and here's the `html`

`html file`

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-sm-9" style="float:right;">
                <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #6f6f6f;">{{ u_form.username.label }}</span>
                {{ u_form.username }}
            </div>
            <img id="img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}"><br>
            {{ p_form.image }} <!-- the image button part -->
</form>
```

this is the important part of the HTML code. The other is just some other stuff. This is where the button is.

so now, if you check this out, it shows no file chosen for the image part. I want that removed. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any documented way to remove it. But adding this to your HTML page will do the stuff.

```
<style type="">
    input[type='file'] {
       color: transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: hi, could you also answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750610/how-to-assign-model-fields-to-a-custom-variable-in-the-view-and-use-it-in-conte