# How to assign model fields to a custom variable in the view, and use it in context to pass to the template?

Tags: python, django

so I have a model in models.py, and it has a few fields. Next, I make a form in forms.py to make a creative form. Then I import that form from forms.py into views.py. In the views.py, I make the create view, with the creat form. But here's the problem. In the views.py, I have the model field space. now I want to do something with that field. I assign a custom variable to this space field and pass it in the context.

But it gives an error called local variable not defined.

`models.py`

```py
class NewJax(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    space = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_created']
        verbose_name_plural = "New Jax"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

`forms.py`

```py
class CreateNewJaxForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewJax
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'space')

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                   'class': 'form-control',
                   'placeholder': 'name your jax'
                }
            ),
            'description': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'add a brief description for jax',
                    'rows': 4,
                }
            ),
            'space': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                }
            )
        }
```

`views.py`

```py
def create_new_jax(request):
    if request.user.username == "Assasinator":
        logout(request)
        return redirect('banned_user')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewJaxForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
            space = form.cleaned_data.get('space')

            result = exec(space)    # I AM TRYING TO SPECIFY THIS CUSTOM VARIABLE IN CONTEXT

            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.title = title
            obj.description = description
            obj.space = space
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()

            return redirect('/create_new_jax/')
        else:
            form = CreateNewJaxForm()
    else:
        form = CreateNewJaxForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "result": result,  # HERE, I PASS IT IN CONTEXT
    }
    return render(request, "editor/jax_create.html", context)
```

so as you see, I made a custom variable result. And I specify it to the space variable from the NewJax model.

Now when I run this, it gives the error.

So if someone could tell me how to pass this variable into context, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

now, if this is solved, i also want the code to execute. That's what `exec` does. So when i print result in my template, it needs to show the output of `space`.

`html file`

```html
{% extends 'editor/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
  <title>Jax | Create New Jax</title>

{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1>Create A New Jax</h1>
        <br><br>

        {{ result }}

        <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }} <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Run</button>
        </form>
        <br><br>

  {% else %}

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      <h2 class="alert-heading">You are not allowed here</h2>
      <p>Go back to the homepage, and login in, or register if you don't have an account. Then you can do what you were doing now.</p>
      <hr>
      <a href="{% url 'ask_section' %}"><p type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Go back to home page</p></a>
    </div>  
  {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

so when i click run, it needs to show the output where i put the `{{ result }}`

please let me know this. Thanks!

Comment: the variable "result" is only defined if request.method == "POST", maybe that's your problem?

Comment: no, i mean, i want that variable `result`, passed into `context`. But it says `local variable not defined`. Is there anyway, i could get `result` with `exec` passed into `context`?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the error is because the part of the code that defines "result" is reached only if it's a POST request, and then you redirect with "redirect('/create_new_jax/')", if your request is anything else (e.g.) a GET request, you don't define "result" in your code, hence, you get the variable not defined error.

Comment: so can you tell how to fix it?

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to achieve but "exec" is NEVER the way! You allow users to run code on your server. This is a bad idea. I could crash your server anytime. I would suggest to check for other solutions. Never use eval or exec! As others pointed out "result" is undefined because you only define it in one "if" case but please rewrite whatever you tried here and then take on the undefined problem.

Comment: alright, do you have any other alternate other than `exec`? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: also, look at this post please, it's just a question for my comment above. on alternates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764022/how-to-get-the-result-of-a-textfield-to-run-python-code-in-django

Comment: So it is possible to let people run code they entered but its not that easy and simply goes beyond the scope of this question. Maybe check how jupyter did it, try something similar yourself. https://jupyter.org/try. I dont know what you are generally trying to achieve but maybe you dont need to execute users code at all?

Comment: ok, i'll explain this. Take a look at my previous comment. The link. Go there, and check out my code. If you noticed, in views.py, i have a create view, and a run view. The create is, where the user codes. The run is where the output of their code is shown. and in the HTML, all the forms are made. Now in the run view, i used `exec`. To return the output. But for now, when i run it, it shows `None` for anything i code in the create view of `views.py`. I don't want `None`. I want the output of the create view. Do you know how? Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  def create_new_jax(request):
    if request.user.username == "Assasinator":
        logout(request)
        return redirect('banned_user')


    result = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewJaxForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
            space = form.cleaned_data.get('space')
    
            result = exec(
                space)  # I AM TRYING TO SPECIFY THIS CUSTOM VARIABLE IN CONTEXT
    
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.title = title
            obj.description = description
            obj.space = space
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
    
            return redirect('/create_new_jax/')
        else:
            form = CreateNewJaxForm()
    else:
        form = CreateNewJaxForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "result": result,  # HERE, I PASS IT IN CONTEXT
    }
    return render(request, "editor/jax_create.html", context)
```

result variable was defined in if scope. So it was local to if function. So define the variable result for overall function with default value. i.e None, empty list or dict.

Comment: ok, thanks. This partly works. But now, i use the `result` variable in my template, and i run it. But when i click run, it doesn't show the output of the code. Could you tell me this please? I'll show my template. Check the description above.

Comment: @TheKingfisher Pass the context like this `return render(request, "editor/jax_create.html", {'context': context })` and in template use it like this `{{ context.result }}` ...

Comment: that doesn't work. I tried an alternate solution. I made a details view of this, and used exec there. But it gives `None`. Please help me with this.

Comment: @TheKingfisher print out the value of the result or use PDB to see the flow of your code and let me know if you are really getting any value in the variable result.

Comment: I'll explain this. Take a look at my comment above. By above, I mean the top. The link. Go there, and check out my code. If you noticed, in views.py, I have a create view, and a run view. The create is, where the user codes. The run is where the output of their code is shown. and in the HTML, all the forms are made. Now in the run view, i used exec. To return the output. But for now, when i run it, it shows None for anything i code in the create view of views.py. I don't want None. I want the output of the create view. Do you know how? Please let me know. Thanks!